# Какой алгоритм ветвления git при фиксе багов в удаленном репозитории?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-remote

Есть удаленный репозиторий, в котором нужно пофиксить баги! Боюсь налажать, поэтому обьясните, пожалуйста точный алгоритм, как следует действовать!

1. клонировал проект
2. создал новую ветку и перешел в нее
3. пофиксих баги и добавил некоторые коммиты в новой ветке
4. смержил с мастером и удалил эту новую ветку
5. запушил на удаленный репозиторий

Все правильно?

Comment: В целом правильно.Но у вас может не быть прав на пуш в `master`, поэтому вы заливаете свою ветку в сетевой репозиторий, и средствами репозитрия создаете *merge-request*

Comment: спасибо за ответ!)

Answer (score 0):

Не указано, о каком проекте идет речь, в проекте 1 фронтенд-разработчик или больше, поэтому предложу безопасный способ внести изменения в любой проект:

1. клонируешь репозиторий
   `git clone <repository>`
2. переключаешься на master-ветку
   `git checkout master`
3. создаешь ветку и переключаешься на нее
   `git checkout -b <branch>`
4. делаешь правки в кодовой базе
5. индексируешь измененные файлы `git add .`
6. фиксируешь изменения `git commit -m '<comment>'`
7. пушишь изменения в удаленный репозиторий `git push`
8. переходишь в репозиторий, создаешь Pull Request через интерфейс твоей [VCS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8) в master, назначаешь code-reviewer-ов при необходимости или просматриваешь самостоятельно свой PR и мерджишь